# Extract Street names from KML document

Tags: google-maps, kml

I got a new Point of Sale system and I need to input all the street names we deliver to. We have a 10 mile radius and as you can imagine...that is a lot of streets. I was able to figure out how to map a radius and output the results into a KML file. Problem I have now, how can I get the list of streets from what seems to be just co-ordinate data in the file.

Comment: What does that KML file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use coordinates data to geodecode:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    // results will have the address
});
```

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

So, you can:

- Parse your KML file and build a list of coordinates
- Iterate through the coordinates and do reverse geocoding
- Keep an addresses list and avoid adding duplicate points if its your case